There is a problem with loading format models.glb in the project on three.js
I'm importing.The glb model is using three, but the model falls apart into the parts it consists of. How can I fix this?
const models = {
  pizza:  { url: 'models/pizza.glb' },
  dodster:  { url: 'models/dodster.glb' },
  cup:  { url: 'models/cup.glb' },
};

const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onLoad = init; // Запуск после загрузки всех моделей

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader(manager);
for (const model of Object.values(models)) {
  gltfLoader.load(model.url, (gltf) => {
    model.gltf = gltf; // Сохраняем загруженную модель в объект
  });
}

I tried to download the model for the game, but it's falling apart

The code you've shared looks OK, but isn't complete enough to help. What happens after the model.gltf = gltf assignement, when and how are the models being rendered?  Please aim to share a minimal, reproducible example.
